# animate scrollTop doesn't work on Chrome?

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome

I use an anchor element like this:

```
<div class="my_centered" id="index_scroll_down_button">
    <a href="#" onclick="smooth_scroll('#intro')">
        <img src="/static/img/scroll-down-icon.png">
    </a>
</div>

<div class="indexcontainer container" id="intro"> 
</div>
```

where the `smooth_scroll` function is defined as:

```
function smooth_scroll(target){
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(target).offset().top - 60
    }, 800);
}
```

This approach works fine on Safari, but does not seem to work on Chrome?
Here is my css:

```
#index_scroll_down_button {
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 0px;
   left: 50%;
   margin-left: -30px;
}
```

Comment: works fine https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YVWqrG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script is running fine, but you have to prevent default anchor click event, in your case to use:

```
<a href="#" onclick="smooth_scroll('#intro'); return false;">
```

But, please try to remove embeded scripts and do something like this:

```js
$('[data-scrollto]').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var target = $( $(this).data('scrollto') );
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: target.offset().top - 60
    }, 800);
});
```

```css
#intro {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
#content {
    height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="intro">
    Intro
</div>
<div id="content">
    Content height 1000px.
</div>
<div class="my_centered" id="index_scroll_down_button">
    <a href="#" data-scrollto="#intro">
        Scroll top
    </a>
</div>
```

Also on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7837dbtd/2/).

Comment: thanks for your comment... in your example you have two ids with intro, which might cause some trouble. I cannot get this working in Chrome. I copied your example but it only works in safari? Also could you say a few words why you prefer your click event over my function?

Comment: I removed the second #intro, was copy/paste from your example code above, should work in Chrome. We should avoid to set inline scripts, same for the styles, both should be set in remote file(s). We should just mark the element with class, id or data attribute for example and later decide what to do with it. That way the changes are easy and we can do reusable scripts. But that is just a comment, the key of your trouble is to prevent default anchor click action, which for local links is go-jump/scroll-to-element.

Answer (score 3):

Animate scrolltop worked for me in firefox but not in chrome and edge. The following css caused the problem:

```
html, body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Comment: So removing that bit fixed the issue? Looks like they don't have such CSS in their code. Please make sure that you answer the question asked, otherwise you are expected to add a comment instead. Best regards